# sftp Broken pipe Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp

I am trying to setup a sftp account to a specific folder. I have created a group `ftpaccess` and user `testuser` with home directory as seen here:

```
sudo addgroup ftpaccess

sudo useradd -d /home/forge/mydomain.com/downloads -m testuser -g ftpaccess -s /bin/false

sudo passwd testuser

sudo chown root:root /home/forge/mydomain.com/downloads

sudo chmod 755 /home/forge/mydomain.com/downloads
```

Then I have created an transfers directory inside `testuser` home folder:

```
sudo mkdir /home/forge/mydomain.com/downloads/transfers

sudo chown testuser:ftpaccess /home/forge/mydomain.com/downloads/transfers
```

Then I have setup `sshd_config` like this (rules added to the end of file):

```
# SFTP account
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now trying to sftp with this user `sftp testuser@localhost` but I get error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you set a password to testuser? So you should type 'sftp testuser:password@localhost'

Comment: @Redbob sure I did with following command "sudo passwd testuser"

Comment: @PrimozRome did you fix your problem? I have the same situation

Comment: The chroot base location has to be owned by `root` in order for chroot to work.  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Please try moving ***Subsystem sftp internal-sftp*** line from your existing block to ***# override default of no subsystems*** in sshd_config

It worked for me.